# How to make random number from int to string

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, swift

I am using Swift to make a math question app I made a generator for a random number but when I run it doesn't work. I want the random number to show in the label.

My code was:

```
    var randomnumber = arc4random() % 10
    randomnumber = QuestionLabel.text
```

How do I code it so it is converted with string format. Thanks

Comment: @nburk I’m sure it’s a duplicate, but not of that, since that’s going the other way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to assign the text of the label to the random number. This is the wrong way around. You will also need to convert the number to a string, you can do this easily in Swift using [String interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292):

```
var randomnumber = arc4random() % 10
QuestionLabel.text = "\(randomnumber)"
```

As a side note `QuestionLabel` shouldn't have an uppercase Q as it does not refer to a class.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a string from any type, you can use either `toString` (in 1.2 or earlier), or `String.init` in 2.0.

Also note that you should use [`arc4random_uniform(n)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) rather than `arc4random() % n` to avoid modulo bias.

So:

```
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
QuestionLabel.text = String(randomNumber) // in 2.0
// or
QuestionLabel.text = toString(randomNumber) // in 1.2
```

Alternatively, if you don’t need the number for anything else, just for some text, you could skip the interim step and use string interpolation with the expression directly:

```
QuestionLabel.text = "\(arc4random_uniform(10))"
```